# mysql full join not working correctly

Tags: mysql

I am using the following mysql to look at user subscriptions. I need to get all the users and in one column show if they have an active subscription or not

This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT `general`.`exchange`.`email`,substring_index(`general`.`exchange`.`name`, " ", 1) as name, `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.`expiryTimestamp`  
FROM `general`.`exchange` 
LEFT JOIN `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`
ON `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.`memberID` = `general`.`exchange`.`id`   
WHERE (`courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.memberID = `general`.`exchange`.`id`)  
AND (`courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.expiryTimestamp > 1443975741)
```

The problem is that it is only returning users who have a subscription. I need it to return all users, and show in a column who has a subscription or not

How can I do this?

Comment: can you add a few rows of example data for each table, and what you expect to get as a result

Comment: Your join is not a `full join` (which MySQL does not support).  It is a `left join`.

Comment: Also don't use double quotes as string parameters, always use single quotes the RDBMs may miss interpret then. The answer from @GordonLinoff show it fixed!

Comment: i think i need full join, not sure how to do it. Not all users from general.exchange have a row in courses.courseSubscriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is turning the `left join` into an `inner join`.  Also, table aliases would make the query easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT e.`email`, substring_index(e.`name`, ' ', 1) as name, cs.`expiryTimestamp`  
FROM `general`.`exchange` e LEFT JOIN
     `courses`.`courseSubscriptions` cs
     ON cs.`memberID` = e.`id` AND (cs.expiryTimestamp > 1443975741) ;
```

The solution to the `LEFT JOIN` problem is to move the condition on the *second* table into the `ON` clause.  Also, you don't need to repeat the join conditions.

If you want a flag, you can add that:

```
SELECT e.`email`, substring_index(e.`name`, ' ', 1) as name, cs.`expiryTimestamp`,
       (cs.`expiryTimestamp`  is not null) as isActiveFlag
FROM `general`.`exchange` e LEFT JOIN
     `courses`.`courseSubscriptions` cs
     ON cs.`memberID` = e.`id` AND (cs.expiryTimestamp > 1443975741) ;
```

Comment: i keep getting Unknown column 'g.exchange.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @Jake . . . That was a typo.  The two table aliases are `e` and `cs` and the appropriate one should be used for all column names.

Answer (score 0):

You've repeated the `join` condition in the `where` clause. Since `null` will never return true in an equality check, this effectively removes the users without any courses and turns your outer join to an inner join. Similarly, the condition on the course's time should also be moved to the join clause:

```
SELECT     `general`.`exchange`.`email`, 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(`general`.`exchange`.`name`, " ", 1) AS name, 
           `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.`expiryTimestamp`  
FROM       `general`.`exchange` 
LEFT JOIN  `courses`.`courseSubscriptions` ON 
           `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.`memberID` =
           `general`.`exchange`.`id` AND
           `courses`.`courseSubscriptions`.expiryTimestamp > 1443975741
```

Comment: I tried this but its only returning rows which exist in the  `courses`.`courseSubscriptions` table, not every user has a row in that table.

Comment: @Jake Forgot about moving the expiryTimestamp condition to the `join` clause too. Mea culpa. Edited and fixed.